# Can't find why Firebase.getFloat returning wrong value

Tags: database, firebase, arduino, nodemcu

```
#include <FirebaseArduino.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#define FIREBASE_HOST "myproject07.firebaseio.com"
#define FIREBASE_AUTH "Xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxvfig"
#define WIFI_SSID "xyz" 
#define WIFI_PASSWORD "12xxxxxx" 

float mv;
String fireStatus = ""; 
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD);
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.print(WIFI_SSID);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print(".\n");
    delay(500);}

  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connected to ");
  Serial.println(WIFI_SSID);
  Serial.print("IP Address is : ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  Firebase.begin(FIREBASE_HOST, FIREBASE_AUTH);

  Firebase.pushFloat("/Num/number", 42.0); 
  // handle error 
  if (Firebase.failed()) { 
      Serial.print("setting /number failed:"); 
      Serial.println(Firebase.error());   
      return; 
  } 

  Serial.print("number: "); 
  Serial.println(Firebase.getFloat("/Num/number")); 
  delay(1000);

}

void loop() {

}
```

I can't find what's wrong with this code. I used `setFloat` to set value and used `getFloat` to get value. It updates my database. Mean it is creating a Num node and setting number value as 42 but when I use getFloat it is showing 0.0. I don't know how to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, it seems to be this issue [Firebase.getFloat returning 0.0](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firebase-arduino/issues/147)

Check if you can retrieve the value as a String. If so, its the bug, if not, then update your question.

An example:

```
// You did your push then
Serial.print("number: ");
float f = Firebase.getFloat("/Num/number");
char err[] = Firebase.error();
Serial.println(f);
Serial.println(err);
delay(1000);
```